# Starting Dev Ops Server For the First Time, Stuck at Hello World

Tags: azure-devops-server-2019

I just installed dev ops server locally using the basic method, which included installing sql express and a new db for the server.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cf3aN.png

I'm now running the url to get to the site which 'should' forward me to start a new project on the default collection, but the url leads to a Hello World page.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnPqo.png

I tried creating a second collection from the default one, but this had no impact.

Attempting to navigate to the collection url results in a 404.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dc69K.png

any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling the whole application, I couldn't find solutions anywhere. I made no changes anywhere in the installation process, and it was successful and acted as expected when connecting to the web page. There must have been some sort of corruption or mistake during installation.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the exact URL `http://localdevops (or http://localdevops:80)` in your first image, there is no `www` or `.com` when you access the server internally.

If you want to access the server via internet, you will need the instructions for [configuring TFS for HTTPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/setup-secure-sockets-layer?view=azure-devops). However, it would be far easier to use [Azure DevOps Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/). Every account gets five free users

Comment: good suggestion, but I used the correct URL. The web browser fills those automatically when it cannot find the site url you originally asked for if it believes you to have mis-typed it.